# Looping through two column to check for condition

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I want to loop through column P and see if there is a cell that has the number "1" in it then at the same time loop through column N to see if there is also a number "1" at same row/column, if there is not a "1" in column N at the same time there is a number "1" in column P, there should be a error message.

Here's what I got started but it doesn't seem to be working so well.

```
    For Each a In Range("p6:p40")
    If a.Value = "1" Then
        For Each c In Range("n6:n40")
            If c.Value = "" Then
            msgbox("check again")
            Else
            msgbox("check again")
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the loop to a regular for loop:

```
For i = 6 To 40
    If Range("P" & i) = "1" Then
        If Range("N" & i) <> "1" Then
            MsgBox "P = 1 but N did not on row " & i
        End If
    Else

    End If
Next
```

Comment: could you msgbox out the excel row the match did not match on?

Comment: @user582635 see edit.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need another loop for column N if you want to check for a value in the SAME row that you're inspecting for column P. Try along the lines of this:

```
Sub test()

For Each a In Range("p6:p40")
    If a.Value = "1" Then
       If a.Offset(0, -2).Value = "" Then
           MsgBox ("blank in row " & a.Row)
       Else
           MsgBox ("not blank in row" & a.Row)
       End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Also, just a tip for debugging: it helps immensely if you have two *different* messages for the two IF branches. Otherwise, how do you know which IF branch just got triggered?

Comment: I tried the above code and even though I had a "1" in the column I'm comparing to, it still show me the msg blank in row ...

Comment: worked fine for me. Check your data.

Comment: This is the route I would have taken, but Scott using column letters is easier to follow for a beginner. +1